# Redirect certain folders using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to figure out how to write an .htaccess rule that will do the following:

```
/example1/removethis/item
```

becomes

```
/example1/item
```

and

```
example2/removethis/item2
```

becomes

```
example2/item2
```

etc.  I should note that 'removethis' is always the same, but I want it to work for anything in the place of 'example1' and anything in the place of 'item', if that makes sense.  I'd also like it to be a 301 (permanent) redirect.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/removethis/(.*)$ $1/$2
```

Should do the trick.  Setting the redirect code and whatnot left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Is there a way to do this such that it only redirects if the new url actually exists?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "exists".

Comment: I mean "going to that url will not result in a 404".  What I'm trying to do is change over the directory structure of some pages to example/item (from example/removethis/item), but I don't have the time/inclination to change them all at once, so it would be nice if it only redirects if example/item exists.  Regardless, your answer works perfectly!

Comment: No, you can't test whether the destination will result in a 404 and then not apply the rewrite, but I can't imagine that the extra redirect to a 404 would be *that* much worse over and above a direct 404.

Comment: Forgive me - I don't really understand what you mean by that last part...

Comment: @womble You could check whether there exists a file that fits this pattern by using a `RewriteCond` directive. eg. `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2 -f`. But like you say, I can't see this being a necessary requirement anyway.

Comment: That'll only work if the resource being requested is a file on disk directly under the document root.  That's a relatively uncommon situation in these days of dynamically-generated everything.